# LinkedIn API: info about companies and groups

Tags: social-networking, opensocial, linkedin-api

I would like to get some data from both users' profiles (about their education, experiences...) and about companies' pages. The first thing seems easy to do, but what's with the second? Can I somehow retreive data about companies? Can I get info which companies a user is following? And can I get a list of groups a user is a member of + info about those groups? It seems to me like LinkedIn API is extremely limited, since I haven't noticed that I can get anything but basic user info...

Thanks,

Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the LinkedIn Developer Forums, there are still no Company or Groups API's that gives access to specific company info available:

http://developer.linkedin.com/search.jspa?peopleEnabled=true&userID=&containerType=&container=&q=company+api

It is possible to get limited information about a company that a particular user has worked for, if that person is a first-order connection.  The Profile API has fields specific to Companies, and has information like company size and industry:

http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1061#company